# How Do I Fix This When One Enemy Is Killed The Others Dispear?

Tags: python, pygame

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/ca0d7ba3afe3d69b4b4c1a3cc14fa684) one the video when I kill one of the enemys they all dispear I dont know why on my code I told it to only make 1 dispear but it isnt working.

```
                # enemys 2
            for enemyshoot in enemyshooting: # all enemys stored in a list
                for bullet in bullets: # player bullets
                    if bullet.rect.colliderect(enemyshoot.hitbox): # if collid with the enemys hitbox
                        if enemyshoot.health > -8: # if the health isnt greater then -1
                            enemyshoot.health -= 1 # keep removing its health
                            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet)) # pop enemys bullet if collided with enemy
                            hitesound.play() # sound
                                    # this function calss the -5 text appearing and dispearing on my screen
                            minusenemyhealthtext()
                        else:
                            for rmv1 in range(len(enemyshooting)-1,-1,-1): 
                                    del enemyshooting[one]
```

Comment: In your else clause, do you really want to be looping over enemyshooting again and deleting them. Shouldn't you just del enemyshoot (ie. the one enemy that your bullet has hit, not all of them)

Comment: else:
                        del enemyshooting[one]         if I just do but if I go all the way to my last enemy and kill him they all die  idk why

Answer (score 0):

```
            # enemys 2
        for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:
            for bullet in bullets:
                if bullet.rect.colliderect(enemyshoot.hitbox):
                    if enemyshoot.health > -8:
                        enemyshoot.health -= 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    else:
                        del enemyshooting[one]
```